# Querying custom post type with 2 custom fields (date-range)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I've searched WP Codex and StackExchange and gotten some clues, but I can't get this query working. I have 2 custom fields associated with each exhibition in Y-m-d format: exstart-date being the start date of the exhibition and exend-date being the ending date.

I can easily display upcoming exhibits and past exhibits, but I cannot get the meta_query right to display current exhibits (with a start date less than or equal to today AND end date greater than or equal to today). The code below displays nothing on the page. Help?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours'));
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'exhibitions', 
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'=>array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'exstart-date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
            ),
        array(
            'key' => 'exend-date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
            )
        )
    ));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: one thing that immediately jumps out is `'type' => 'CHAR'`, should be `'type' => 'DATE'`, no?

Comment: I tried using DATE and it still didn't work. When I do the query for only the start date or only the end date, CHAR works fine.

Comment: the only other thing is that `caller_get_posts` is a true/false parameter, but has been replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`, though that shouldn't really affect the query, you just get a deprecated notice. I tried it here and it seems to be working, maybe verify that nothing else is interfering with the query, like a plugin, `print_r($wp_query)` and inspect the contents.

Comment: Thanks, but print query did not reveal anything. Something is wrong with the relational meta_query. If I query exstart_date or exend_date by themselves, no problem; I get the right result. But the combined query returns nothing.

Comment: if something is wrong with the query, you'd see it in the generated SQL when you inspect `$wp_query`. it works as-is for me when I just copy/paste your code and add the proper meta fields (i'm also changing the post_type to one I already have set up). are your meta field dates formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`? I don't imagine the other queries you're doing would work if they weren't.

Comment: Yup: yyyy-mm-dd
Maybe I implemented print query wrong.
Again, the queries work separately, but not in tandem.

Comment: Shouldn't the compare value be '=', since you're trying to check that they both contain today's date?

Comment: They don't contain today's date. We're looking for values equal to or greater than the start date and equal to or less than the end date. I also tried this query removing the '=', so that it looks for values between the start and end dates, but that did not return a result either. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the logic, which is possible.

Comment: The part we're interested in is `$wp_query->request`, that'll give you the actual SQL query that's being sent to the db. if you've got phpMyAdmin, as a sanity check, you can paste that query in directly under the SQL tab to see what it returns. [This is what mine looks like](http://pastebin.com/SMkPav1L). other than post_type, yours should look the same, unless something else, like a plugin, is filtering the query.

Comment: I don't have phpMyAdmin access on this particular site.

Comment: I noted you used the same date as start and end dates. Did you try it when the two dates were different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I ended up with that works. I should have mentioned that the query was inside the loop, because when I showed it to Damian Taggart of Mindshare Studios, he noticed that he said I should be using WP_Query instead of query_posts. Thanks to Milo and others for attempting to help me without having all the necessary info.

```
<?php
     $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours'));
     $myquery = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'exhibitions', 
     'posts_per_page' => 6,  
     'paged' => $paged,
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'meta_query'=>array(
            'relation'=>'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'exstart-date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'CHAR'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'exend-date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'CHAR'
            )
        )
    ));
    if ($myquery->have_posts()) :
    while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
?>
```